# Are "array" and "&array[0]" completely interchangeable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, function-call

Yes, it has been asked before, many times, but I wanna know which one is more advisable?

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int addr[8];
} usr_command;

usr_command* p_usr_command;

int foo(int* parameter)
{}
```

So which one is less prone to be problematic?

```
foo(p_usr_command->addr);
```

or

```
foo(&p_usr_command->addr[0]);
```

?

Comment: Try `sizeof(array)` versus `sizeof(&array[0])`.

Comment: @EOF and, ironically, that is exactly the difference. this is not the same case, however.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No. *Exactly* the difference would be: `sizeof` *and* `_Alignof` *and* `&`.

Comment: @EOF I think slight misunderstanding, we're both on the same page, you're answering the title, while i was referring to the exact case in the question body. :)

Comment: "*problematic*" in which sense?

Comment: Your two cases are semantically equal. The difference is in the impression it gives to the reader. The first case gives impression that the function expects an array, i.e. it will use indexation on it. The second case suggests that you are passing a pointer to a single element.

Answer (score 8):

In ***this*** case ( *passing an array name* vs. *passing the address of the first object in the array* as function argument), both the snippets are equivalent.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1, *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators* (*emphasis mine*)

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. [....]

However, in general, they are ***not the same***.

- `array` is an *array* of type `int [8]`
- `&(array[0])` is a *pointer*, type `int *`

As already suggested by [EOF in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329242/are-array-and-array0-completely-interchangeable/41329292#comment69861587_41329242), try passing both variants to the `sizeof` operator and check the result to get the hands-on output.